# How to get Hindi voice using google translate/google cloud

Tags: python, text-to-speech, google-translate, hindi

I am building a personal assistant, which requires to speak back in hindi. I find it weird that google cloud text to speech doesn't offer hindi language,

https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/voices

while google translator speaks back if you ever translate from english to Hindi and click on speaker button.

https://translate.google.com/

So, I read on Internet that

https://translate.google.com.vn/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&q=ANYTHING_TEXT&tl=en&client=tw-ob

can do the trick. But it is for english. SO if i change the `tl` to `hi`, it should work if i replace `ANYTHING_TEXT` to anything in hindi, but doing so gives me these results:

[https://translate.google.com.vn/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&q=आप%20कैसे%20हैं&tl=hi&client=tw-ob](https://translate.google.com.vn/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&q=%E0%A4%86%E0%A4%AA%20%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%88%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%87%20%E0%A4%B9%E0%A5%88%E0%A4%82&tl=hi&client=tw-ob)

it is giving me audio I cant understand.

So, my questions are

1) Why we cant access hindi voice using google cloud and can using google translate?

2) How to work around to get hindi voice working in my python file.

3) Google cloud offers google translation api but it only translates the text and gives text at output and not audio. Tell me please if it's true.

https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/

Answer (score 0):

1) It seems that Google has already developed its Hindi voice which can be used as best effort in a free service such as Google Translate, but if it isn't good enough as you point out, they may be improving it before supporting it for the paid TTS service.

2) You would have to use an alternate TTS service that supports the hindi language until this language gets supported by the Google's TTS API.

3) Yes, the Translation API is only meant for text. You could use the output of the Translation API as input for the TTS API, but since it doesn't support the language you want, you may have to submit a feature request to the [Google Cloud's Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#search_for_or_create_bugs_and_feature_requests_by_product) to show interest in the Hindi language support for this service.